# Rewire drone motor

Tags: motor, weight, wiring

I am working on a new design that I need a motor to run independently without a computer.  I essentially want to connect a drone motor that has three wires to a battery + and -.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?  I have read on the differences with the motors.  This is a bit out of the box, but I would like to utilize the small size, light weight,and as much power as I can get.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, "outside of the box."

Comment: Sorry to add again, I don't need to vary the speed.  I want it to be at full power always. If it does need a ESC, do you have any suggestions on the simplest one?  It only needs to run the motor on at full.

Comment: In order to run it without an ESC, you could get a Brushed DC motor and connect it directly to the + and -.  You will need an ESC or some form of inverter to power your three phase BLDC motor.

Answer (score 1):

Brushless motors require a controller, because they need power switched between their three wires as they rotate. These are fairly complex devices because they detect the position of the rotor relative to the magnets, and switch power accordingly, thousands of times every second. Brushless motors have only become common in the last couple of decades because the computing power required has become cheap enough to fit on a speed controller.

If you really want to use that motor, you will need a speed controller. You're probably best to buy one, and use an Arduino to generate the PWM signal required to drive it. That would be easier than trying to make your own. I don't know of any speed controllers that will just start up at full power when connected to a battery. They all have a fail-safe, intended to protect you from exactly that.

If you want a motor that can be connected directly to a battery, you should use a brushed motor. They have a commutator, which is a mechanical device that switches power between the coils as they rotate past the magnets.